# Heart attacks & suicides in NASA Mission Control of the 60s?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, history, mission-control, project-gemini

On page 280 of Mike Gray's book *[Angle of Attack: Harrison Storms and the Race to the Moon](http://Angle%20of%20Attack:%20Harrison%20Storms%20and%20the%20Race%20to%20the%20Moon)* (1992), Gene Kranz, legendary NASA flight director in Gemini & Apollo missions, is quoted as saying:

> It was like bootcamp. We took our best controllers and made them instructors. They hammered away at the weak links until they broke. [...] Some guys died of heart attacks. Some others committed suicide.

Nevertheless, having finished Kranz's own memoir *[Failure is not an option](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Failure_Is_Not_an_Option.html?id=s9eOX7Sr6KkC&redir_esc=y)* (2001), I was unable to find the slightest reference to such dramatic events as deaths due to heart attacks or suicides among flight controllers.

Any pointers or references? Or is the first quote just an exaggeration?

Comment: It was done in a shuttle sim once. Sim sup got a flight controller to fake a heart attack on console. Management said, no more. https://blogs.nasa.gov/waynehalesblog/2010/02/16/post_1266353065166/

Comment: @OrganicMarble thanks, but this is obviously different; it was part of a simulated scenario, and nobody actually died.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it just reminded me of it. Hence comment, not answer. Anyway, Kranz doesn't mean on console, just in their life.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, I don't take it to mean on the console either; in their life, indeed, but during their service as controllers, not later